# Remove duplicate elements from custom object List

Tags: java, date, collections, hashmap

I have List with following information.

```java
    public class PriceDetails {
        public String materialId;
        public String price;
        public String priceEndDate;
    
    }
```

List data is as follows:

```
    List<PriceDetails> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
```

```
priceList1 [priceEndDate=2022-04-29 00:00:00.000000, price=1.59, materialId=10054700],
priceList2 [priceEndDate=2022-03-31 00:00:00.000000, price=1.64, materialId=10054700],
priceList3 [priceEndDate=2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000, price=3.1, materialId=10063200]]
```

I want to create another list with following information from above one.
As we can see, priceList1, and priceList2 have materialId same. So I need to take the one whose priceEndDate is latest among first two dates. So my resultant list should be as below,

```
priceList1 [priceEndDate=2022-04-29 00:00:00.000000, price=1.59, materialId=10054700],
priceList3 [priceEndDate=2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000, price=3.1, materialId=10063200]]
```

I tried this so far:

```
    for(PriceDetails unit :priceList) {
                    if(map.containsKey(unit.getmaterialId())) {
                        map.put(unit.getmaterialId(), <notgettingwhattoputhere>));
                    }else {
                        
                    }
                }
```

Please help in achieving same.

Comment: What's wrong with it? What is the error?

Comment: Wanted to know how i can remove priceList2 object from list based on priceEndDate

Comment: Do not store dates and times in strings. Use the `LocalDateTime` type (or `LocalDate` if you do not need the time of day).

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer to your question. But try to avoid having price and priceEndDate as a String.

```
    static class PriceDetails {
        public String materialId;
        public String price;
        public String priceEndDate;

        public PriceDetails(String materialId, String price, String priceEndDate) {
            super();
            this.materialId = materialId;
            this.price = price;
            this.priceEndDate = priceEndDate;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("[materialId: %s, price: %s, priceEndDate:%s]", this.materialId, this.price, this.priceEndDate);
        }
    }
    public static void filter() throws ParseException {
        List<PriceDetails> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
        PriceDetails priceList1 = new PriceDetails("10054700", "1.59", "2022-04-29 00:00:00.000000");
        PriceDetails priceList2 = new PriceDetails("10054700", "1.64", "2022-03-31 00:00:00.000000");
        PriceDetails priceList3 = new PriceDetails("10063200", "3.1", "2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000");
        priceList.add(priceList1);
        priceList.add(priceList2);
        priceList.add(priceList3);
        Map<String, PriceDetails> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(PriceDetails unit :priceList) {
            if(map.containsKey(unit.materialId)) {
                if((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(unit.priceEndDate)).after((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(map.get(unit.materialId).priceEndDate)))) {
                    map.put(unit.materialId, unit);
                }
            } else {
                map.put(unit.materialId, unit);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map.values());
    }
```

Output:

```
[[materialId: 10054700, price: 1.59, priceEndDate:2022-04-29 00:00:00.000000], [materialId: 10063200, price: 3.1, priceEndDate:2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to collect the data in the list and pick up the latest price, then retrieve the `values()` from the obtained map, providing that `PriceDetails` class has relevant getters for its member fields:

1. using the following collectors:

- [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to group the price details by their ids
- [`Collectors.maxBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-) to find the latest price detail with the help of [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) by the appropriate getter (here the price end date)
- [`Collectors.collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to convert the `Optional` returned at the previous step into appropriate `PriceDetail`:

```java
List<PriceDetails> latest = new ArrayList<>(
    data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            PriceDetails::getMaterialId,
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.maxBy(
                    Comparator.comparing(PriceDetails::getPriceEndDate)
                ),
                Optional::get
            )
        ))
        .values()
);
```

2. Using [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with merge function using [`BinaryOperator::maxBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
List<PriceDetails> latest = new ArrayList<>(
    data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            PriceDetails::getMaterialId,
            price -> price,
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                Comparator.comparing(PriceDetails::getPriceEndDate)
            )
        ))
        .values());
```

---

Without Stream API, the reduced list may be retrieved similarly from the map of priceId to the price using [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function:

```java
Map<String, PriceDetails> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (PriceDetails pd : data) {
    map.merge(pd.getMaterialId(), pd, BinaryOperator.maxBy(
        Comparator.comparing(PriceDetails::getPriceEndDate)
    ));
}
List<PriceDetails> latest2 = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing optimized solutions .

Answer (score 1):

Modified the **PriceDetails** class so that it has a Constructor and a `toString()` method:

```
public class PriceDetails {
    
    public String materialId;
    public String price;
    public String priceEndDate;

    // Constructor:
    public PriceDetails(String materialId, String price, String priceEndDate) {
        this.materialId = materialId;
        this.price = price;
        this.priceEndDate = priceEndDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "priceEndDate = " + priceEndDate + ", price = " + price + ", materialId = " + materialId;
    }
}
```

The following method parses object details in order to carry out some comparisons with date. Dates are converted to [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) then the [LocalDate#isBefore()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javatime/javatime_localdate_isbefore.htm) and [LocalDate#isAfter()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javatime/javatime_localdate_isafter.htm) methods are used. Read the comments in code:

```
public List<PriceDetails> removeLesserDateDuplicates(List<PriceDetails> priceList) {
    List<PriceDetails> wrkList = new ArrayList<>();
    wrkList.addAll(priceList);
    
    // Current list Element loop...
    for (int i = 0; i < wrkList.size(); i++) {
        
        // Get current element priceEndDate (without the time component).
        String iEndDate = wrkList.get(i).priceEndDate.split("\\s+")[0];
        // Get current element materialId.
        String iID = wrkList.get(i).materialId;
        
        // List element comparison iterator loop...
        for (int j = 0; j < wrkList.size(); j++) {
            
            // Get iterator element priceEndDate (without the time component).
            String jEndDate = wrkList.get(j).priceEndDate.split("\\s+")[0];
            // Get current element materialId.
            String jID = wrkList.get(j).materialId;
            
            /* Is the Current ID a duplicate of another List element ID 
               and are the dates Not Equal....          */
            if (i != j && iID.equals(jID) && !iEndDate.equals(jEndDate)) {
                
                // Yes....
                // Convert the current element Date to LocalDate.
                java.time.LocalDate iDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(iEndDate);
                
                // Convert the iterated element Date to LocalDate.
                java.time.LocalDate jDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse(jEndDate);
                
                /* Is the current element Date before the iterated element Date?
                   If so, remove the current element record from the List.     */
                if (iDate.isBefore(jDate)) {
                    wrkList.remove(i);
                    i--; // Reduce iterator loop increment by 1.
                }
                
                /* Otherwise, is the current element Date after the iterated element Date?
                   If so, remove the iterated element record from the List.     */
                else if (iDate.isAfter(jDate)) { 
                    wrkList.remove(j);
                    j--; // Reduce current element loop increment by 1.
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return wrkList;
}
```

To use this method yo might do something like this:

```
/* Fill the priceList List with PriceDetails instances using 
   its constructor (see the `PriceDetails` class).        */
List<PriceDetails> priceList = new ArrayList<>();
priceList.add(new PriceDetails("10054700", "1.59", "2022-04-29 00:00:00.000000"));
priceList.add(new PriceDetails("10054700", "1.64", "2022-03-31 00:00:00.000000"));
priceList.add(new PriceDetails("10063200", "3.1", "2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000"));
priceList.add(new PriceDetails("10054700", "1.58", "2022-04-30 00:00:00.000000"));
priceList.add(new PriceDetails("10063200", "3.88", "2022-02-18 00:00:00.000000"));
    
List<PriceDetails> anotherPriceList = removeLesserDateDuplicates(priceList);
    
/* Display the anotherPriceList List within the Console Window.
   To see why the displayed result is as it is, look at the ID 
   values and the Dates (yyyy-MM-dd) carefully.             */
for (PriceDetails pd : anotherPriceList) {
    System.out.println(pd.toString());
}
```

When run with the example data, the Console Window should display:

```
priceEndDate = 2022-05-26 00:00:00.000000, price = 3.1, materialId = 10063200
priceEndDate = 2022-04-30 00:00:00.000000, price = 1.58, materialId = 10054700
```